# replace ',' by 'c' in C

Tags: c

Hello there I'm beginner and learning bases of C. I'm trying to replace all ',' that users could write by some '.' for my programm can run and read it. For now when I launch it doesn't took the number after the comma.
If I write in the console whit a dot it's okay

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functiun.h"
#include <string.h>

int lire(char *chaine, int longueur)
{
    char *positionEntree = NULL;

    // On lit le texte saisi au clavier
    if (fgets(chaine, longueur, stdin) != NULL)  // Pas d'erreur de saisie ?
    {
        positionEntree = strchr(chaine, '\n'); 
        if (positionEntree != NULL) 
        {
            *positionEntree = '\0'; 
        }

        return 1; 
    }
    else
    {
        return 0; // On renvoie 0 s'il y a eu une erreur
    }
}
double lireDouble()
{
    char nombreTexte[100] = {0}; // 100 cases devraient suffire

    if (lire(nombreTexte, 100))
    {
        // Si lecture du texte ok, convertir le nombre en double et le retourner
        return strtod (nombreTexte, NULL);
    }


    else
    {
        // Si problème de lecture, renvoyer 0
        return 0;
    }
}

double virgulePosition (char *chaine, int longueur)
{
     char *virgulePosition = NULL;

     if (fgets(chaine, longueur, stdin) != NULL)
         {

          virgulePosition = strchr(chaine, ',');
          if (virgulePosition != NULL)
          {
              *virgulePosition = '.';
          }
         }

     return strtod (chaine, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, for example by showing us a [mcve].

Comment: I also suggest you learn how to use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement (while monitoring variables and their values) to see what's really going on.

Comment: The specific problem is that you use an `if` statement where you ought to use a `while` loop.

Comment: you're doing it wrong. You just need to set the correct locale and the value will be parsed correctly regardless of the radix and thousands symbol. No need to replace `,` with `.`

Answer (score 1):

First off all try to do not mix code which does something with the I/O functions. For example the character replace is a great candidate to be a fuunction

```
char *strreplace(char *haystack, char needle, char replace)
{
    char *saved = haystack;

    if(haystack)
    {
        while(*haystack)
        {
            if(*haystack == needle) *haystack = replace;
            haystack++;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}
```